# How to set the size of a QGraphicsView?

Tags: qt, user-interface, graphics

I'd like to have a fixed size `QGraphicsView`, which I want to add to a layout together with some other widgets. However, the `QGraphicsView` simply ignores `resize()`, here is the relevant code:

```
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;
QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
view->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt::black, Qt::SolidPattern));
view->resize(1000, 600);

QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->setMargin(0);
layout->addWidget(view);
setLayout(layout);
```

If I use `setFixedSize()` instead of `resize()`, the size is actually being set correctly. However, it seems that the window size is not updated, the window is not centered properly.

How am I supposed to set a fixed size for a `QGraphicsView`?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but in case anyone else stumbles into it: you can set both `minimumSize` and `maximumSize` to the desired target size, and it should work regardless of what layout the `QGraphicsView` is in.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right you want to have QGraphicsView centred inside the window and having fixed size. You need rather then VBoxLayout you should use QGridLayout with spacers, so your form should look like:

```
 <Empty>        <VSpacer>     <Empty>

 <HSpacer>   <GraphicsView>   <HSpacer>

 <Empty>        <VSpacer>     <Empty>
```

Comment: No, I don't want it centered, I just want it to have a certain size.

Comment: can you post some screenshot with setFixedSize applied?